# Is it ethical to invite your supervisors for dinner before graduation?

Tags: phd, advisor, ethics, germany

I plan to finish my PhD thesis this year, but I will likely not be able to defend it this year, because my supervisors obviously need time to review it.

However, I will leave the country by the end of the year as well and it is not clear yet, whether I need to come back for the defense or whether it can be done remotely. In case I do not come back to Germany, I would still like to have a last social gathering with my two supervisors to say goodbye and express my gratitude. We had dinners in the past (usually when a collaborator from a different country would meet us here in Germany) and so far it was always them who have covered the bill.

If it was a normal social gathering, I'd expect it to be the norm that one party does not always covers the expenses but it is shared among all participants somewhat equivalently (I pay this time, you pay next time, ... ).

But given that they are my supervisors and will have to grade me, I wonder if this is ethical.  Perhaps an arrangement like pay dinner for yourselves, I'll cover the drinks, will make it less problematic? I do not expect the expenses for any single meal+drinks to be over 20€.

Comment: Frankly if you expect the meal plus drinks to be 20€ pp in Germany, it may well be that your advisors will politely decline…

Comment: @Oбжорoв I'm not sure what you mean by "20€" in Germany? A meal is usually around 8-14€ and 1 or 2 drinks will probably add around 3-6€. Do you think this is very expensive or do you think it is too cheap and they do not want to go? If it is the latter, then I'm very sure they won't find it "cheap".

Comment: "so far it was always them who have covered the bill": Most likely these bills were not paid by your supervisors privately but by the expense budget for such meetings.

Comment: @Oбжорoв: to give some numbers to compare with, my professional society stated a few months ago that they consider 35 € per person a good limit for typical, and will not reimburse more than 50 € per person (implied: not even if the president of the society dines with the ministry of science)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Taking a person out to a (reasonable) dinner as a "thank you" is a custom that appears in many societies. As a Ph.D. thesis is a long relationship between people, offering to take your advisors out to dinner as a thank you is within reasonable bounds of this custom---even before you graduate. Technically, they are grading you, but a Ph.D. is not like an undergraduate class.

In some cases, a person may not be allowed to accept such an offer. Common examples include government employees and people with a potential business conflict of interest. If you *know* that such a rule applies to somebody, it would be rude to offer something you know they cannot accept.

For most professors, however, there is no such rule between them and their students, and if one applies here that you are unaware of, it would be up to the professor to inform you and to decline.

That said: in the professor-student relationships I have observed, the direction often goes the other way, i.e., with professors buying for their students rather than the other way around. This can be about [power dynamics](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/8427/how-can-i-get-someone-to-stop-paying-for-my-meal), "[paying it forward](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pay_it_forward)," or even just the simple pragmatics that students often have little money.

**Bottom line: invite them out, but don't be surprised if they turn the tables and end up taking you out instead.**

Comment: In Germany there *is* such a rule: Anything over 5 € in value (in my state, Berlin) I am not allowed to accept from anyone, student or otherwise, without permission from the dean. So pens, yes. Dinner at a restaurant, no.

Comment: @DeboraWeber-Wulff Good to know! How routine is such a permission? Like, would it be unthinkable to ask the dean, or would it be easy to say: "My student wants to take us out to dinner, can we have permission?"

Comment: depends on the dean. Our dean would make a note of it (so that no accusation of bribery can be made) and permit it, but others would not. Luckily, I didn't have to make such a decision as dean myself. I did permit flowers and wine that were > 5€ presented after the oral exam. Since the OP may not be personally in Germany after the oral exam, I would suggest a heartfelt, hand-written thank-you letter sent with nice stamps from your country. Something like that means much more to me than any presents. I really treasure former students who take time to write to me!

Comment: @DeboraWeber-Wulff Would you be willing to write an answer yourself, as well?

Comment: Sorry to -1, but any such invitation **before the defense** (and even more so shortly before) would be totally unacceptable in Germany. It would not only be something the professors must decline, but is also something the PhD candidate should never even mention. Too close to attempting bribery.

Answer (score 6):

I can give you my perspective of someone who used to supervise students and their theses at a German university. You did not mention what kind of institute you worked at, but as you mentioned "grading" I'll assume that you and your supervisors work at a state university, as industry and research institute supervisors typically are not responsible for the grading.

Therefore, they are most likely to be either a civil servant or an employee of the respective German state. In consequence, they are either not allowed to accept presents or only up to a very small amount (~ 10 euros if I remember correctly), depending on the state and the type of contract. And this is before even taking into account that they will be grading you.

My advice is therefore **not to do it** or to directly ask them about their opinion- it creates a dilemma for your supervisors and might open them AND you to malicious gossip.

A suggestion: Do you know about the German "Ausstand"? If an employee leaves a group or company they typically bring food, either for breakfast in the morning or cake at coffee time for the whole group. If it's a group where parting employees get a small gift from the co-workers there might be a small speech. The monetary amount is (more or less) negligible and it serves as a nice opportunity to say thanks and goodbye to everyone (thus not directly aimed at your boss).

Comment: Dinner invitations are not generally considered "presents" (in the academic context) - otherwise, people would be breaking the law all the time.

Answer (score 2):

### Inviting your supervisors to dinner before the defense is unacceptable

I'd like to emphasize what @Debora Weber-Wulff already stated in a comment:

University professors  in [germany](/questions/tagged/germany) are typically public officers and subject to strict anti-corruption laws. Other employees in public institutions are typically bound by their contract to the same rules.
The anti-corruption regulations already forbid anything that could be read as corruption by others; and they apply to both sides: the supervisors cannot accept *and OP is not allowed to offer*.

In general, as  @Debora Weber-Wulff said, acceptable gifts or invitations are limited to negligible monetary value even *after* all exams are over.
Shorly *before* the final exams/grading, such an invitation is totally unacceptabe since it could be seen as an attempt by OP to bribe their supervisors. This would not only be a problem for OP's supervisors but also for OP.

---

### What is acceptable

- Inviting the supervisors along with everyone else in your group (AND)
- when there is a reason: you leaving, your defense being over, birthday, ...
- again, the value should not be too high per person.

@Kajo mentioned the Ausstand which is on the order of magnitude of cake and coffee for the whole group (note: not only the supervisors).
A similar occasion would be directly after the defense (in-person obviously) - then possibly with added sparking wine.

What I'm familiar with after the defense between different groups in Germany was in the range between: a "hallway-party" one evening at the institute (fresh PhD bringing the food such as buns, butter, cheese, cold cuts and pickles as well as beer, coke and juice for the whole group, the whole group helps preparing the buffet from these or PhD buys already prepared buns). Or somewhat more elaborate food (cooked, BBQ), but then either a few fresh PhDs join forces, or join forces with a workplace birthday party and/or there's a certain potluck component (PhD provides a "basis", and everyone else brings something).

But never anything of non-negligible monetary value to the supervisors or commission *only*.